# How to pass proxy to pythonbrew for downloading setuptools?

Tags: python, proxy, pythonbrew

I installed pythonbrew on an ubuntu precise system.  Had some issues using proxy during the installation (see [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969343/pythonbrew-does-not-install-python-with-no-output-on-command-line)).  Now I'm able to install different versions of python and switch between them, however setuptools is not installed during python installation:

```
ERROR: Failed to install setuptools. See /usr/local/pythonbrew/log/build.log to see why.
Skip installation of setuptools.
```

The build.log contains:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "distribute_setup.py", line 556, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "distribute_setup.py", line 552, in main
  tarball = download_setuptools(download_base=options.download_base)
File "distribute_setup.py", line 211, in download_setuptools
  src = urlopen(url)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 389, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 502, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 421, in error
  result = self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 597, in http_error_302
  return self.parent.open(new)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 383, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 401, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1138, in https_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1105, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Looks to me like the issue is with the proxy again and I'm not sure what script to modify so that the setuptools installation uses my proxy.  I modified distribute_setup.py and added proxy information there (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection)), but it looks like this file is overwritten each time pythonbrew install is called.  I am new to python and can't find where this file is generated from.  Any pointers as to how I can pass proxy to the setuptools part of the installation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in the env solved this particular problem (after that the error changed from 110 to 113; for a follow up [see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990935/urlopen-error-errno-110-with-https-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-12-10)).